# `How apply multiple event on single button?`

Tags: javascript, vue.js, sass, vuejs2, vue-component

How apply multiple event on single button in Vue.js?

I have a single button component

When a button is clicked in parent, several events are
must be applied

1. tytle should change from **"Buy" to "In a basket"**
2. icon shold apply **done**
3. style should change to **button_1**

***my button component***

```
<template>
  <div class="btn"
       @click="click"
       :class="className">
    <i class="material-icons"> {{ icon }} </i>

      <span> {{ title }} </span>

  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    title: {
      type: String,
      default: 'Buy'
    },
    disabled: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false
    },
    button_1: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false
    },
    icon: {
      type: String,
      default: ''
    },
  },
  data() {
    return {}
  },
  computed: {
    className() {
      return {
        'btn__disabled': this.disabled,
        'btn__button_1': this.button_1,
      }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    click() {
      this.$emit('click')
    }
  },
  name: "BaseButton"
}
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped>

.material-icons {
  font-size: 16px;
}
.btn {
  position: relative;
  font-family: 'Merriweather', sans-serif;
  color: var(--color-primary-light);
  left: 45%;
  bottom: 18%;
  height: 48px;
  width: 122px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: var(--color-grey-light-4);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  align-items: center;

  &:hover,
  &:active {
    background-color: var(--color-grey-light-2);
    border: none;
  }

  &__button_1 {
    color: var(--color-primary-light);
    background-color: var(--color-grey-light-3);
    border: none;
  }
  &__disabled {
    background-color: var(--color-grey-light-1);
    border: none;
    pointer-events: none;
  }
}
</style>
```

***my parent component***

```
<template>
<base-button @click="clickBtn"></base-button>
</template>

<script>
import BaseButton from '../components/ui/BaseButton'
export default {
  name: "GalleryOverview",
  components: {BaseButton},
    methods: {
      clickBtn() {
        console.log('BTN clicked')
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

*How can I apply multiple event on single button?*

Comment: What have you tried, i dont see any code.

Comment: You don't "apply an event". You _listen_ for an event ("click" is an event), and when this event happens, you execute a function (in your case, `clickBtn()`). In this function, you can perform as many actions as you want. Change your title and other things in there.

Comment: @Grumpy if you don't see any code, it's a problem on your end, because the question clearly includes the code of two components

Comment: @JeremyThille My bad, to fast.

Comment: Can you suggest an easy way with button_1 plss

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost done, as you are sending `emit` to parent component, you can use that to change.

So, first you will need to pass the required props to the child component, as:

```
<template>
<base-button @click="clickBtn" :title="title" :icon="icon" :button_1="button_1"></base-button>
</template>

<script>
import BaseButton from '../components/ui/BaseButton'
export default {
  name: "GalleryOverview",
  data() {
    return {
      title: 'My Title',
      icon: '',
      button_1: false
    }
  }
  methods: {
    // This is where you can change.
    clickBtn() {
      this.icon = 'change icon';
      this.title = 'change title';
      this.button_1 = true;
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Now when you click the button it will change the `title`, `icon` and `button_1`.

Comment: U-Dev thanks a lot ! sorry but a have not 15 reputation to make the status of your answer "This answer is usefull!" (

Comment: U-Dev can you suggest an easy way with button_1 plss